# Change color of a svg+xml;base64 image

Tags: html, css, svg

This is my code:

```
.arrow
{
  position: relative;
  bottom: -2rem;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  /**
   * Dark Arrow Down
   */
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: contain;
}

.bounce {
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

The image in the `background image` is black. I want to change the color of this image. Can I add an overlay or something? Or do I ***have*** to create a new svg+xml;base64 image? Beacause I do not know how to do this.

Comment: What kind of color do you want to change?

Comment: The color of the arrow-image in the "background-image:" into DodgerBlue (#1E90FF)

Comment: decode it from base64 to a string, replace the colour in the string, then encode the new data to base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. You will have to create another image.

Comment: Thanks! Is the process to create that hard?

Comment: I tryed what  Robert Longson tells us : Decode the base64 to UTF-8 then you got this : an xml version of the SVG, you change the color by #1E90FF and encode the string to base64. And then you got your picture :)